# WPF/WinForms/GDI interop: converting a WriteableBitmap to a System.Drawing.Image?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, writeablebitmap, winforms-interop

How can I convert a WPF WriteableBitmap object to a System.Drawing.Image?

My WPF client app sends bitmap data to a web service, and the web service needs to construct a System.Drawing.Image on that end.

I know I can get the data of a WriteableBitmap, send the info over to the web service:

```
// WPF side:

WriteableBitmap bitmap = ...;
int width = bitmap.PixelWidth;
int height = bitmap.PixelHeight;
int[] pixels = bitmap.Pixels;

myWebService.CreateBitmap(width, height, pixels);
```

But on the web service end, I don't know how to create a System.Drawing.Image from this data.

```
// Web service side:

public void CreateBitmap(int[] wpfBitmapPixels, int width, int height)
{
   System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = ? // How can I create this?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this blog [post](http://kodierer.blogspot.com/2009/11/convert-encode-and-decode-silverlight.html) shows how to encode your WriteableBitmap as a jpeg image. Perhaps that helps?

If you really want to transfer the raw image data (pixels) you could:

1. create a [System.Drawing.Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) with the correct size
2. iterate over your raw data, convert the raw data to a System.Drawing.Color (e.g. via [Color.FromArgb()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color_members.aspx) and set each pixel color in the newly created image via [SetPixel()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.setpixel.aspx)

I'd definitely prefer the first solution (the one described in the blog post).

Comment: Thanks. I'll play around and see if any of this helps.

Answer (score 4):

If your bitmap data is uncompressed, you could probably use this `System.Drawing.Bitmap` constructor: [Bitmap(Int32, Int32, Int32, PixelFormat, IntPtr)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy1a2d14.aspx).

If the bitmap is encoded as jpg or png, create a `MemoryStream` from the bitmap data, and use it with the [Bitmap(Stream)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw.aspx) constructor.

EDIT:

Since you're sending the bitmap to a web service, I suggest you encode it to begin with. There are several encoders in the [System.Windows.Media.Imaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608877.aspx) namespace. For example:

```
    WriteableBitmap bitmap = ...;
    var stream = new MemoryStream();               
    var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder(); 
    encoder.Frames.Add( BitmapFrame.Create( bitmap ) ); 
    encoder.Save( stream ); 
    byte[] buffer = stream.GetBuffer(); 
    // Send the buffer to the web service
```

On the receiving end, simply:

```
    var bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap( new MemoryStream( buffer ) );
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: My data is simply wpfWriteableBitmap.Pixels, which returns an int[]

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of how to encode the bitmap before you send it, and how to decode it in the web service.

Answer (score 0):

The question is for WPF, and `Pixels` does not appear to be a property of `WriteableBitmap`. Some of the answers here point to SilverLight articles, so I suspect this might be a difference between WPF and SilverLight.