# Convert System.windows.Controls.Image to System.Drawing.Bitmap

Tags: c#, image-processing, kinect

The questions says it all. I have looked at numerous example and googled a lot but nothing seems to work.

This is my code:

```
System.Windows.Controls.Image abc = Image;
// SaveImageToJPEG(abc, "C:/1.jpg");

FindShape(new System.Drawing.Bitmap((Image.Source as BitmapImage).StreamSource));
```

The line : `(Image.Source as BitmapImage)` returns `null`.

So, how to get a bitmap from System.windows.controls.Image ?

This question is pretty different from all the ones out there.. I tried everything and it did not work for me. But finally I found the solution. Unfortunately, I cannot post it as an answer because people here at stackoverflow were so very eager to close it down. **Anyway..here is the answer:**

System.Windows.Controls.Image abc = Image;

```
            MemoryStream ms = null;
            JpegBitmapEncoder jpegBitmapEncoder = null;
            BitmapEncoder bencoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();

            System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = null;
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

            if ((int)abc.Source.Width>0)
            {
                RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)abc.Source.Width,
                                                                               (int)abc.Source.Height,
                                                                               100, 100, PixelFormats.Default);
                renderTargetBitmap.Render(abc);

                jpegBitmapEncoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
                //jpegBitmapEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));
                bencoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));
                using (ms = new MemoryStream())
                {

                    bencoder.Save(ms);

                    //if (ms != null)
                    {
                        bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ms);
                        //bmp.Save("C:/bmp_thing.jpg");

                        if (bmp != null)
                        {

                            count++;
                            if(count ==60){
                            int shape_type =FindShape(bmp);
                            Tetris_Game.NextBlockType = shape_type;


                            count = 0;
                            }
                            //  open_img.Dispose();

                        }
                        bmp.Dispose();
                        //ms.Flush();

                    }

                }

            }
```

Comment: But that link is for BitmapSource. How do I convert image source to bitmap source? . I tried (Image.Source as BitmapSource) I get an error

Comment: The Source needs to be a BitmapImage from the start for you to retrieve it. Are you setting up a Uri as Image.Source and expect to get a BitmapImage out of it after it has downloaded it?

Comment: I get the image from KinectDevice...ie from the camera. I don't know what format it is in. All i know is, that the image from camera is assigned to 'System.Windows.Controls.Image'.

Comment: Can you draw the Image on a WriteableBitmap and get your copy from there?

Comment: How do I do that? I don't know how to do that. I have not worked with C# much .

Comment: See WriteableBitmap.Render(UIelement, Transform) method here  methodhttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.render(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: On what object do i call the above methods? I don't have a System.Windows.Media.Imaging object...Should I convert System.Windows.Controls.Image to an Imaging object?

Answer (score 0):

Give [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) a spin and try to render your Image element on it. After that you create your System.Drawing.Bitmap by copying the pixels since WriteableBitmap gives you raw access to them.

After you have created your WriteableBitmap take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239449/wpf-winforms-gdi-interop-converting-a-writeablebitmap-to-a-system-drawing-image) on how to convert it to a Bitmap.

Comment: How Do I initialize the WritableBitmap? Where do I get BitmapSource from ?

Comment: There is no render method for WriteableBitmap either

Comment: WriteableBitmap is a BitmapSource. What .NET version are you on? There should be a constructor or method that takes in a UIElement.

Comment: how do I find that out now?